# Thread Safety and static functions

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let's suppose I have a :

```
class base
{
    base(){f(this);};

    static void f(base * b) {(b->d)++;};

    int d;
};
```

Now if on 2 separate threads I create an object of type base, would method `f` be considered thread safe?
I am asking this question because usually from what I know is that for a method to be thread safe it should not use static members nor global variables. But as you can see from the above example I decided not to make variable `d` static, instead I call it through the running instance of base.

Also,  I think I don't need to protect this line : `(b->d)++;` with a mutex since each thread will have a separate instance of base and of variable d.

Am I correct in my analysis? is there anything I should be careful about?

Comment: you are correct, as long as the base pointers are thread specific you are good.

Comment: Are you able to compile your program? It should throw up a compilation error

Comment: @stamhaney, no I haven't I am just trying to work out the theory :) please point out the problem though

Comment: The constructor should be under public access

Comment: Doesn't HAVE to be under public access (singletons are generally made with private/protected constructors), but for most use cases, sure. I think it's clear this is just an example, though, and the brain's compiler is much more relaxed than the CPU's.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, your constructor is thread safe, because it accesses only instance variables (specifically, `d`). It does exhibit undefined behavior, because it reads from uninitialized `d` to perform the increment, but that has nothing to do with thread safety.

Here is how you can fix undefined behavior:

```
base(): d(0) {f(this);};
```

Now that `d` is initialized in the initializer list, your program behaves in a predictable way.